# Can I use a numpy array to generate folds for cross validation?

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I would like to use a numpy array to build folds for a k-folds cross validation task. Taking out the test slice is easy, but I can't figure out how to return the remainder of the array, with the test slice omitted.  Is there an efficient way to do this?

```
examples = range(50)
classes = range(50)
data = np.array(zip(classes,examples))
test_slice = data[5:10]
train_on_remainder = ??
```

Comment: Concatenate slices on either side; the result will be a copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set it up like so:

```
test_slice, remainder = np.split(data.copy(), [test_size], axis=0)
# run test
remainder[:test_size], test_slice = test_slice, remainder[:test_size].copy()
# run test
remainder[test_size:2*test_size], test_slice = test_slice, remainder[test_size:2*test_size].copy()

# etc.
```

I don't think you can have it with much less copying.

How it works:

```
.      full set:            | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
       split (full copy)       / \
       tst / rem         | 0 |     | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
         run trial
                             | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
       swap tst and           ^ |
       first segment:         | v
       (partial copy)        | 0 |

       tst / rem         | 1 |     | 0 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
         run trial
                             | 0 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
       swap tst and               ^ |
       second segment:            | v
       (partial copy)            | 1 |

       tst / rem         | 2 |     | 0 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
         run trial
                             | 0 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
       swap tst and                   ^ |
       third segment:                 | v
       (partial copy)                | 2 |
```

etc. As you can see it is almost literally shifting the fold. Saving many full copies.

Answer (score 1):

sort of an odd question given that one normally would use sklearn's `train_test_split()` if its available.

**edit: another approach might be**

```
r = np.arange(len(data))
trainX = data[r < 5 | r > 10]
```

an efficient solution I'm not sure but try this
build the indexers using a list comprehension.

```
def indx(n, test_slice):
    return [x for x in range(n) if, x not in test_slice]

test_slice = set(range(5, 10))
trainX = data[indx(len(data), test_slice))]
```

of course you should you something like sklearn's `train_test_split()` if its available.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to manually implement the k-fold approach for arbitrary number of splits: I've used the following solution (to make train and validation set for cross validation):

```
#Generate indices on the row-wise length of the whole 
#array

fold_indices = np.arange(x.shape[0])

#Shuffle the indices -- if you want, but not 
#neccessary
np.random.shuffle(fold_indices)

#Split the indices into k-parts (returns a list of 
#numpy arrays)
eval_indices = np.array_split(fold_indices, k)
for e in eval_indices:
  #Define the evaluation set for the current fold
  eval_set_x = x[e]

  #exclude the upon parts indices from the 
  #whole array (similarly on the upon answers)
  
  mask_eval = np.ones(x.shape[0], bool)
  
  #Set indices of the eval set to false
  mask_eval[e] = False

  #Subset by the bool array:
  train_set_x = x[mask_eval]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
split = np.vsplit(data, np.array([5,10]))

'''This will give you a list with 3 elements'''

test_slice = split[1]
train_slice = np.vstack((split[0],split[2]))
```

> [[5 5]  [6 6]  [7 7]  [8 8]  [9 9]]
>
> [[ 0  0]  [ 1  1]  [ 2  2]  [ 3  3]  [ 4  4]  [10 10]  [11 11]  [12
>   12]  [13 13]  [14 14]  [15 15]  [16 16]  [17 17]  [18 18]
>       …    [47 47]  [48 48]  [49 49]]

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches, demonstrated on a 1d array:

```
In [64]: data = np.arange(20)
In [65]: test = data[5:10]
In [66]: rest = np.concatenate((data[:5],data[10:]),axis=0)
In [67]: rest
Out[67]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
In [68]: 
In [68]: mask = np.zeros(data.shape[0], dtype=bool)
In [69]: mask[5:10] = True
In [70]: test = data[mask]
In [71]: rest = data[~mask]
In [72]: rest
Out[72]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
```

There is a `np.delete` function

```
In [75]: np.delete(data, np.arange(5,10))
Out[75]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
```

Internally it uses one of the two methods I demonstrated.