# How to slice array to exclude one row?

Tags: python, numpy

As a part of cross-validation need to split train array into N folds. And then for every fold run an experiment. The latter means that I need to combine N-1 folds into one array and use the remaining fold for validation.

Assuming I have binary_train_X as initial array and want to split it into 5 folds. I got some code which works:

```
num_folds = 5
train_folds_X = []

# Split the training data in folds
step = int(binary_train_X.shape[0] / num_folds)
for i in range(num_folds):
    train_folds_X.append(binary_train_X[i*step:(i+1)*step])

# Prepare train and test arrays
for i in range(num_folds):
    if i == 0:
        train_temp_X = np.concatenate((train_folds_X[1:]))
    elif i == num_folds - 1:
        train_temp_X = np.concatenate((train_folds_X[0:(num_folds - 1)]))
    else:
        train_temp_X1 = np.concatenate((train_folds_X[0:i]))
        train_temp_X2 = np.concatenate((train_folds_X[(i+1):(num_folds)]))
        train_temp_X = np.concatenate((train_temp_X1, train_temp_X2))
    test_temp_X = train_folds_X[i]

    # Run classifier based on train_temp_X and test_temp_X
    ...
    pass
```

Question - how to do it in more elegant way?

Comment: There is a function for doing this in sklearn, it can do what I think you are trying to do here, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html You will aslo find ton of other validation methods, also you should have a look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html, to find out which model parameters perform best.

Comment: For an efficient solution see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42592737/7207392

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do this instead:

```
splits = np.array_split(binary_train_X, num_folds)

for i in range(num_folds):
    fold_train_X = np.concatenate([*splits[:i], *splits[i + 1:]])
    fold_test_X = splits[i]
    # use your folds here
```

If you want to use a prebuilt solution, you can use `sklearn.model_selection.KFold`:

```
kf = KFold(num_folds)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(binary_train_X):
    fold_train_X = binary_train_X[train_index]
    fold_test_X = binary_test_X[train_index]
    # use your folds here
```

Comment: Thanks! It complained "function can take only 3 parameters" about np.concatenate([*splits[:i], *splits[i + 1:]]). The solution is to use np.concatenate(([*splits[:i], *splits[i + 1:]]))

Comment: @ZakiMa That shouldn't be the case; adding parentheses like that shouldn't do anything, and the code as I wrote it works for me. Could you please check again?

Comment: Ha! My bad. I missed one set of square brackets and ended up with (*splits[:i], *splits[i+1:]). This resulted in that error. In this case wrapping helps. Thank you!